# Axiomatically prove □(A ∨ ¬B), ¬□A, ⊢ ◇¬B in modal system K

Tags: logic, modal-logic, symbolic-logic, axiom

This time I have a more "complex" problem at first glance. I need to create a direct proof using the axioms of system K and rules of inference, but I have been unable to do so.

□(A ∨ ¬B), ¬□A, ⊢ ◇¬B

```
 □(A ∨ ¬B),      premise 1
 ¬□A,            premise 2
 □(¬A → ¬B),     introduction of implication
 □¬A → □¬B       axiom K
 ¬¬□¬A → ¬¬□¬B,  double negation of the previous step
 ¬◇A → ¬◇B
 ¬¬◇¬A,          from premise 2
 ◇¬A             elimination of double negation
```

No matter what I do, I can't find a way to use modus ponens between premise 2 and premise 1 so I only get □¬B from it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: So to paraphrase, if it's necessary that either A or not B, and it's not necessary that A, then not B is possible.  Semantically, this should make sense - If all accessible worlds are (Av¬B) worlds, but not all accessible worlds are A worlds, then presumably they include a ¬B world! So it's about finding the right logical tools in K to do this - you'll probably find Distribution and Necessitation can help you set things up!

Answer (score 2):

Please show that these derived rules hold.

(i): ☐(A -> B) -> (◇A -> ◇B)

(ii): ~☐A -> ◇~A.

Now recall that A or B is classically equivalent to ~A -> B.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the best at modal logics, but I can try my hand at it, at the very least, perhaps it will set you down the right path, here we go:

□(A ∨ ¬B),      premise 1

¬□A,            premise 2

□(¬¬B → A),     the introduction of implication from (1)

□(B → A),       simplification

□B → □A,        axiom K

¬□B ∨ □A,       Demorgan's law [(p→q)≡(¬p∨q)]

¬¬◇¬B ∨ □A,     the definition of □

◇¬B ∨ □A,      simplification

```
 ◇¬B         (From 2 & the previous step)
```

I’m not sure that this is satisfactory, but let me know. Thanks

Comment: hey this sounds good. Can you please explain the last two steps (i.e. getting ◇¬B  from ◇¬B ∨ □A?

Comment: @ l0ner9 I did that through a disjunctive syllogism. If we have ◇¬B ∨ □A and we also have ¬□A then we can simply follow the format of the simple syllogistic argument: 

P v Q, ~Q, Therefore P. 

The same can be done in the last step:

◇¬B ∨ □A; ¬□A; Therefore ◇¬B. 

Let me know if you have anymore questions.

Comment: could I have added an additional step where I transformed ◇¬B ∨ □A into ¬ □A --> ◇¬B, and used modus ponens with premise two?

Comment: Yes, you could transform it using Demorgan’s law as you have done above and use modus ponens to derive your answer, but that would be a superfluous step. Your professor might subtract points depending on his grading system, but yes, you could most definitely add that extra step.